# Pygame Surface.fill() not work but my code has not any errors

Tags: python, pygame

```
import sys
import pygame


def run():
  pygame.init()

  screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))

  while True:
    screen.fill((255,0,0)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if(event.type == pygame.QUIT):
        sys.exit()

    pygame.display.flip()

run()
```

I don't know why my screen (created by pygame) **is still gray not (255,0,0)**

I use:

- pygame version: 1.9.4
- python version: 3.7.1
- Platform: Mac OSX

Comment: sorry, this line " pygame.display.set_caption(ai_settings.caption) " should delete but not effect my question

Comment: It's because of an issue with SDL on MacOS. See the linked question; especially Rene's answer.

Comment: The closing bracket is missing in `screen.fill((255,0,0)`

Comment: sorry, I deleted it when I put the code on stackoverflow,but my code is work well except my sreen not change bgcolor